# How can I set the initial value of a dijit.form.DateTextBox to today?

Tags: dojo

I've created a DateTextBox like:

```
<input dojoType="dijit.form.DateTextBox" constraints="{max: Date.now()}" id="startDate" />
```

When the page loads there is no value in the field. I would like the value to default to today. Is there a way to handle this? I know I could use the "value" attribute and set it in the  declaration, but that only allows me to put a static date in the field, not a dynamic date.

It would also be good if the solution works with a form reset too.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ugh, the input got messed up using html tags... my mistake... it should be:
&lt;input dojotype="dijit.form.DateTextBox" id="startDate" /&gt;

Answer (score 20):

The parser supports the "now" keyword, so you could do:

```
<input dojoType=dijit.form.DateTextBox value="now">
```

Of course, for programmatic creation you would simply do:

```
new dijit.form.DateTextBox({value: new Date()})
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It's a pity I couldn't find it in the documentation!?!

Answer (score -1):

Your solution:

```
<input dojoType=dijit.form.DateTextBox value="now">
```

If you want to make the date other than today:

```
<input dojoType=dijit.form.DateTextBox value="now" constraints="{max: new Date()}">
```